# How to extend variable lifetime when borrowing

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm preparing a script for PDB information extraction. Currently I cannot use `info` variable even once because of its short lifetime.

I get 'borrowed value does not live long enough' error with the code below.

I understand this happens because of `info.symbols()?` borrow, but I ran out of ideas on how this could be fixed.

How can I append the items into `mod_symbols`?

Relevant library code ([github.com/willglynn/pdb](https://github.com/willglynn/pdb)):

```rust
pub struct PDB<'s, S> {
    msf: Box<dyn Msf<'s, S> + 's>,
    dbi_header: Option<DBIHeader>,
    dbi_extra_streams: Option<DBIExtraStreams>,
}

impl<'s, S: Source<'s> + 's> PDB<'s, S> {
    pub fn module_info<'m>(&mut self, module: &Module<'m>) -> Result<Option<ModuleInfo<'s>>> {
        Ok(self
            .raw_stream(module.info().stream)?
            .map(|stream| ModuleInfo::parse(stream, module)))
    }
}


pub struct ModuleInfo<'s> {
    stream: Stream<'s>,
    symbols_size: usize,
    lines_size: LinesSize,
}

impl<'s> ModuleInfo<'s> {
    /// Get an iterator over the all symbols in this module.
    pub fn symbols(&self) -> Result<SymbolIter<'_>> {
        let mut buf = self.stream.parse_buffer();
        buf.truncate(self.symbols_size)?;
        if self.symbols_size > 0 {
            let sig = buf.parse_u32()?;
            if sig != constants::CV_SIGNATURE_C13 {
                return Err(Error::UnimplementedFeature(
                    "Unsupported symbol data format",
                ));
            }
        }
        Ok(SymbolIter::new(buf))
    }
}
```

My script:

```rust
fn dump_pdb<'a>(filename: &str, imagebase: u64) -> pdb::Result<()> {
    let file: File = std::fs::File::open(filename)?;
    let mut pdb: PDB<File> = pdb::PDB::open(file)?;
    
    // ...
    
    let dbi: DebugInformation = pdb.debug_information()?;
    let mut modules: ModuleIter = dbi.modules()?;
    
    // merge the module functions
    let mut mod_symbols: Vec<pdb::Symbol> = Vec::new();
    
    while let Some(module) = modules.next()? {
        println!("Module: {}", module.object_file_name());
        let info: ModuleInfo = match pdb.module_info(&module)? {
            Some(info) => info,
            None => {
                println!("no module info");
                continue;
            }
        };

        while let Some(symbol) = info.symbols()?.next()? {  // `info` does not live long enough
            mod_symbols.push(symbol);                       // borrow later used here
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0597]: `info` does not live long enough
   --> examples\pdb_symbols2json.rs:251:34
    |
251 |         while let Some(symbol) = info.symbols()?.next()? {
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
252 |             mod_symbols.push(symbol);
    |             ------------------------ borrow later used here
...
282 |     }
    |     - `info` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it looks like [most](https://docs.rs/pdb/latest/pdb/struct.ModuleInfo.html) [types](https://docs.rs/pdb/latest/pdb/struct.Symbol.html) in `pdb` have a hidden lifetime argument.

IMO, you should write `pdb::Symbol<'_>` and `pdb::Module<'_>` to make that apparent. I expect that a future Rust edition will make not writing the lifetime argument a hard error.

About your particular situation, I don't know the details of that crate, but I guess that your `mod_symbols` is storing values ultimately borrowed from `info`, so one should outlive the other. But you are creating and destroying `info` with each iteration of the loop, and that would invalidate the values stored in the `mod_symbols`.

You can try storing the `info` values in an outer scope. Something like this (untested):

```
    // infos lives longer than mod_symbols!
    let mut infos: Vec<ModuleInfo<'_>> = Vec::new();
    let mut mod_symbols: Vec<pdb::Symbol<'_>> = Vec::new();

    while let Some(module) = modules.next()? {
        println!("Module: {}", module.object_file_name());
        let info = match pdb.module_info(&module)? {
            Some(info) => info,
            None => {
                println!("no module info");
                continue;
            }
        };
        infos.push(info);
    }
    for info in &infos {
        while let Some(symbol) = info.symbols()?.next()? {
            mod_symbols.push(symbol);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sadly this results in 'cannot borrow `infos` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable' at `infos.push(info)`

Comment: fyi, moving the inner `while` loop outside fixed the errors (it resulted in a 25GB allocation runtime error when testing but that's out of scope for this question)

Comment: @mimak: Indeed, I should have seen that. Let me fix the answer. About the 25GB I guess that the intended use is to just store the data you need from the `Symbol`  and not the symbol itself?

Comment: i wanted to devide the symbol data into equal chunks for parallel processing, but for large pdb files that results in up to a million items, i guess i accumulated too much in a single vector. anyway thanks for help

Comment: @mimak: I think I've done something similar with `rayon`: it required the `Item` type to be `Send` but not `'static`, so it might work for you.